# How do i lazy load entities inside aggregate if repositories are not allowed inside it

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, lazy-loading, repository-pattern

I was recently reading DDD and came across the guideline that repositories are not allowed inside our aggregates. Now, If we follow this guideline then it would mean that we have to load all the entities and value objects inside aggregates when we create/restore the root from database, but what if the number of entities/value objects are huge and i want to lazy load them, how do i achive that without access to repository, what is the standard way of achiving this.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Aggregates is to separate entities into isolated chunks. You can then load those chunks all at once. Sure you can use lazy-loading if your ORM supports that and you don't always need the whole aggregate, but that's just a bonus.

When you need to load some related aggregates, you should get id (or id's) from one aggregate and use those to load from other repositories.

In DDD, you can also implement the code that uses multiple aggregates in services.

If you really need to access those data inside your aggregate, maybe the aggregate boundaries aren't right and it should also contain those extra data (e.g. having a list of OrderedItem inside your Order).

Comment: Suppose i have an aggregate consisting of entity1 and entity2 where entity 1 is the root and holds a reference to entity2, now i want to perform `entity1.getEntity2()` or `entity1.someEntity2Operation()` where entity2 is supposed to be lazily loded, how will i achive that if i don't have access to my repository and by the extension of it, my database. You touched on getting id instead of actual object and then using ot to get items, is it the standard way of doing things or is there some other way to achive this